# Data transfer between android device and web services

Tags: android, web

I want to transfer data between android device and web services .I have the data stored in the local database . Now i want it to be sync with web service .
Can someone plz. help me out ...how should i start..?

Comment: JSON Or XML? SOAP or RESTful?

Answer (score 0):

Use `HttpClient` for communication and sending data to the web service either via GET or POST request and do googleing for HttpClient example.